# PHP and Wordpress - Submit URL using wp_http

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a URL that is generated by php and ends up as a string called $myurl and looks like this...

http://www.mydomain.com/submit.php?favcol=blue&favfood=crisps&favday=Tuesday

I am trying to use the following snippet to submit this url

```
$request = new WP_Http();
$response = $request->post($myurl, array());
```

It is not working, although if I submit the URL manually then it does work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** I've just checked the `class-http.php` file and I'm wrong, there is a post method defined.

```
function post($url, $args = array()) {
    $defaults = array('method' => 'POST');
    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    return $this->request($url, $r);
}
```

Which is still just a function created specifically to do:

```
$request->request($myurl, array('method'=>'post', 'data' => 'whatever'));
```

Alternatively, you can just use the wrapper that was created explicitly for this.

```
wp_remote_post($url, array());
```

Comment: I have tried wp_remote_post($myurl, array()); but still not working

Comment: @fightstarr20 Could you please `echo` the statement, as it will return an error that an assist better.

Comment: echoing it just gives me 'array'

Comment: @fightstarr20 Good. Then do `echo '<pre>', print_r($request->post($myurl, array())), '</pre>';`

Comment: I get  Undefined variable: request and Call to a member function post() on a non-object

Comment: @fightstarr20 Did you instantiate it first by calling the class...?

Comment: Now i get Array ( [headers] => Array ( [content-length] => 0 [connection] => Close ) [body] => [response] => Array ( [code] => 400 [message] => Bad Request ) [cookies] => Array ( ) [filename] => )

Comment: @fightstarr20 What's the data look like in `array()` that you're posting?

Comment: array is blank, I am just trying to post $myurl as is

Comment: @fightstarr20 There's your issue. Refer to the above answer for your resolution. Or move the `favcol=blue&favfood=crisps&favday=Tuesday` into an array and pass it along to be a `POST` request.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but it seems to me that you are not posting anything actually, but use the url so the page can handle the GET paramaters from the url? Try this:

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/submit.php?favcol=blue&favfood=crisps&favday=Tuesday';
$request = new WP_Http;
$result = $request->request( $url );
```